# Cakephp Mysql find non-repeating values

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have the following table named `persons`. I need to find out only unique (non-repeating) amounts.

```
     id | amount
     1  | 20
     2  | 20
     3  | 30
```

I tried doing `$this -> Person -> find('all', array('fields' => 'DISTICT amount'));`

In the output I got amount 20, 30 instead of only 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a 'full' answer, but this may help you. In plain SQL, this should be something like;

```
SELECT amount, COUNT(*) FROM persons GROUP BY amount HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This should return all 'unique' amounts (please test if that is returning the right information).

Maybe this helps you, however I'm not at my computer to try to rewrite this to a CakePHP `find()`